# When does Community ♦ vote to close a question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

As the title says, when would the Community moderator vote to close a question?

> [Example](https://askubuntu.com/q/613766/176889):
>
> [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the OP of the question agrees that their post is a duplicate, a binding vote by the Community user is cast and closed.

See this MSE post for more details: [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/203389)

Comment: @2mkgz Yes, it is always possible for OP to agree that their post is a dupe, and above a certain rep level, they can vote to close their own post. Apparently, for the second set of users, this does allow them to unilaterally (technicalities aside) close their question (see comments on the Meta.SE post).